# SVG Circle vs HTML border-radius 50%

Tags: css, svg

I am writing a mobile/web app which has coloured clickable and movable circles.
I am aware of the fact that I can draw them in two ways:

1. A div using `border-radius`
2. A `<circle>` in a `<svg>`

Now considering the fact that with svg I can take advantage of doing cool animations, why one over the other?

Comment: What is the intended use of these shapes?

Comment: an svg will scale much better responsively, and svgs have excellent cross browser support. Animation libraries like d3.js have excellent animation support svgs that will let you get the exact animation your looking for. With all of that being said at the end of the day this is purely an opinion based answer to what you are more comfortable using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to depend on what you're going to do with the circles.

If they're just buttons for a link, stick with a `div`, But if you're going to do all sorts of animation or create a game, I might go with SVG as it's more flexible but not supported by some old or mobile browsers.

I will update this answer with more info if you answer my question comment.